# Submitted Chrome extension: "manifest is invalid" on download

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I recently submitted a chrome extension, but when I try to download the extension it says that the manifest file is invalid. Not sure why.

Here is my manifest :

```
{
    "name": "My chrome extension",
    "version": "0.2",
    "description": "My chrome extension description.",
    "permissions": [ "activeTab", "tabs", "contextMenus" ],
    "background": {
        "persistent": false
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "favicon.png",
        "default_popup": "index.html"
},
 "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Is there a tool online where I can validate a Chrome extension manifest file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `scripts` in your `background` item.

```
{
    ...
    "permissions": [ "activeTab", "tabs", "contextMenus" ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
           "path/to/js/script",
         ], 
        "persistent": false
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "favicon.png",
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    ...
}
```

**OR** just remove the background item from your manifest if you are not planning on using it.

```
{
        ...
        "permissions": [ "activeTab", "tabs", "contextMenus" ],
        "browser_action": {
            "default_icon": "favicon.png",
            "default_popup": "index.html"
        },
        ...
    }
```

--

You don't need tools to test the manifest, go to the chrome://extensions page, enable developer mode on the top right and load your extension, it will tell you the error and how to solve it.

Comment: Thank you ! Indeed it was the background to remove

Comment: In addition to loading an extension unpacked, a developer can pack an extension locally (though the resulting package will only really work on the same machine). Installing an extension packaged this way will perform all the checks that a "real" install would. However, there's some differences between that logic and the webstore upload verification (which is the reason for the question in the first place) - some extensions may pass browser checks but not Web Store checks.